# Creating a JSON file once, when the server first starts

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I am trying to create a json file once(server first loads), so that I can later just reference to that json file instead of rendering that JSON every time a user request that page.

I have a valid json. I checked it with firefox and [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), but when I try to create a file with node.js and that previously checked JSON I get an error.

First I create that file it works(and it is filled, but only the first time with a new file name, if I use the same file name again the file will be empty...) and as soon as I load it, this files becomes empty and I get that error(actually I don't know when it becomes empty, that's my problem I don't know where the error is..).

The error:

```
module.js:489
    throw err;
          ^
SyntaxError: ...\data\my.json: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:486:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\routes\projects.js:72:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

I am using

```
fs.unlink
```

and

```
fs.writeFile
```

I don't understand whats going on here, totally strange ...

ps.: I am using Express.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code creating the file in `createDataOnceWhenServerFirstTimeStarts` is asynchronous. So when you try to load the JSON, it may not have been written yet.
There is another issue in case the file already exists: `fs.unlink` is also asynchronous and you don't wait for this step to finish before writing the file.

If this initialization needs to be done before the server starts listening, I suggest you use only synchronous fs methods:

```
exports.createDataOnceWhenServerFirstTimeStarts = function () {

var myData = ...;//get data from funciton call
var outputFilename = "data/my.json";

if (fs.existsSync(outputFilename)) {
    try {
        fs.unlinkSync(outputFilename);
        console.log("File deleted successfully!");
    } catch (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
} else {
    console.log("File does not exist!");
}

var dataToWrite = JSON.stringify(myData);//,null,4);
try {
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFilename, dataToWrite);
    console.log("JSON saved to " + outputFilename);
} catch (err) {
    return console.log(err);
}
};
```

Btw you do not necessarily need to delete (unlink) the file first, `fs.writeFile` will overwrite it if it exists.